# Will a 1500VA autotransformer do the job for an appliance with 13A and 120V?

Tags: electrical

I have a device that says it is 1500W. However looking at the specs, it says it is 13amps at 120V. If I multiply A x V then that is actually 1560W.

I'm just wondering, if I then get a transformer rated for 1500VA(1.5kVA) is that actually enough or am I starving my device from that extra 60watts?

Comment: It depends an *awful* lot on what the "device" is, or to be more precise whether 1500W is a constant load, intermittent or merely a max spec.  For instance a PC might have a 1500W power supply, but not likely to use anything near that, unless you put in 4 video cards and 12-drive RAID array, and even then only on spin-up.   A Kill-a-Watt is your friend.  You can surge a transformer over its rating for a short time.  The transformer can't prevent this unless it is fused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't starve your device. You might cause the transformer to run a little warmer than normal but probably not by a measurable amount. Although transformer current is also limited by the magnetic field in the core, this limit won't be so close to the rating that you should be concerned.

The rating plate may not be this clear but I strongly suspect that it's not that your appliance draws 13A, but that it's fused at 13A, drawing less. Initial current may be another matter especially if most of the load is a motor.

If I already had the transformer I'd try it (but maybe measure the current). If I was buying the transformer I'd probably go for the next size up if possible

Comment: That is interesting. Thanks. The specs of my device on paper say 12.5A (which does work out to be 1500W) but underneath on the label attached to the device it says 13A. I don't have the transformer yet, I was about to purchase but wanted to be sure how it is all calculated and if there is room for error or margins.

Answer (score 2):

I would mostly agree with Chris H. Short answer is you are fine using the 1.5KVA transformer.

Longer answer:

120 volt devices in the US such as blow dryers, curling irons, space heaters, etc. are allowed to be labeled and marketed as 1500 watts. In reality, they draw less than the 12.5 amps that 1500 watts would require at 120 volts. The National Electrical Code requires cord and plug connected loads cannot exceed 80% of the rating of the branch circuit. That means a 15 amp circuit is only good for a 12 amp single load. So, devices can be marketed at 1500 watts but in reality would be designed for 1440 watts but that isn't a nice round number and marketers like nice round numbers.

Additionally, these are all nominal voltages and power ratings and can vary by some 5 to 10 % depending on manufacturing and design tolerences. Not to mention, the system voltage is also a nominal voltage and your "120" volt system could vary anywhere from 115 to 125.

So, your transformer is close enough.

Good luck!

Edit:

> 210.23(A)(1) Cord-and-Plug-Connected Equipment Not Fastened in Place. The rating of any one cord-and-plug-connected utilization equipment not fastened in place shall not exceed 80 percent of the branch-circuit ampere rating.

Comment: That 125%/80% rule is for continuous loads, and is normally used when you have a dedicated or circuit for a major appliance/device.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of the limit on Cord-and-Plug-Connected Equipment Not Fastened in Place. I have edited my answer accordingly.